# plotly dash : how to draw y axis in different ticks?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

For example, I create a scratter to show the percentage difference between real sale_count and my model predicted sale_count of some products :

### [image]

```
percentage_difference = (predict_value - real_value)/real_value
```

Most of points mainly locate in 0 ~ 1 . (percentage 0% ~ 100% )
As we know, there are always some outliers in the data, some of them may exceed 10 .

So I want to display the plot y axis in : `[-10, -5, -1, 0, 1, 5, 10]`

```
500% ~ 1000% with length 1
100% ~ 500% with length 2
0% ~ 100% with length 3
0% ~ -100% with length 3
-100% ~ -500% with length 2
-500% ~ -1000% with length 1
```

But I don't see an example in docs.

Answer (score 0):

For manual range of axes

```
    layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[2, 5]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        range=[2, 5]
    )
)
```

for more info https://plot.ly/python/axes/#setting-the-range-of-axes-manually

Comment: This is not what I asking. You set range 2~ 5 with certain length 0.5

Answer (score 0):

You should try look at [tickvals](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-tickvals) and [ticktext](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-ticktext) parameters. I think they will help you here. `tickvals` specify how much ticks you want to see at `yaxis` and `ticktext` set the text for each of ticks (for `0` set the text of tick to value from `percent_difference[0]`).

Suggested code for `layout`:

```
layout = dict(yaxis=dict(title="Percents values",
                         # Choose what you want to see on yaxis! In this case list
                         tickvals=[i for i in range(len(percentage_difference))],
                         ticktext=percentage_difference
                         )
              )
```